# Add row to dataframe if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following dataset:

[image: dataset]

If Crack == "Y", I will need to add 2 new rows using name from Outright1 and Outright2.  However the position from Outright2 will be multiplied by -1.

I have applied the following method:

```
for i in data.index:
    if(data.Crack[i]=="Y"):
        new_row = {'Position':data['Position'][i],'Contract':data['Outright1'][i],'Outright1':np.nan,'Outright2':np.nan,'Crack':"N"}
        new_row2 = {'Position':data['Position'][i]*-1,'Contract':data['Outright2'][i],'Outright1':np.nan,'Outright2':np.nan,'Crack':"N"}
        data = data.append(new_row, ignore_index = True)
        data = data.append(new_row2, ignore_index = True)
```

and managed to get my desired output:
[image: desired output]

However was just wondering if there is any better and more efficient way to code this?

Comment: I don't know what can be more efficient or better than `data[data['Crack']=='N']`. You can look into masking numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt` to reformat your dataframe:

```
out = df.melt(id_vars=['Position'], value_vars=['Outright1', 'Outright2'],
              var_name='Type', value_name='Contract').dropna(subset=['Contract'])

out = out.assign(Crack='N',
                 Position=np.where(out['Type'] == 'Outright2',
                                   out['Position']*-1, out['Position'])) \
        .drop(columns='Type')
```

```
>>> pd.concat([df, out], ignore_index=True)

   Position Contract Outright1 Outright2 Crack
0         1     ICFX       NaN       NaN     N
1        -1     ICFY      ICFA      ICFB     Y
2         1     ICFZ       NaN       NaN     N
3         1     ICFW      ICFY      ICFY     Y
4        -1     ICFA       NaN       NaN     N
5         1     ICFY       NaN       NaN     N
6         1     ICFB       NaN       NaN     N
7        -1     ICFY       NaN       NaN     N
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
spreads = data[data["Crack"]=="Y"].drop(["Contract", "Crack"], axis=1).set_index("Position").stack().rename("Contract").reset_index()
#flip the position for outright2
spreads["Position"] = spreads["Position"].where(spreads["level_1"]=="Outright1", -spreads["Position"])

output = data[data["Crack"]=="N"][["Position", "Contract"]].append(spreads[["Position", "Contract"]], ignore_index=True)

>>> output
   Position Contract
0         1     ICFX
1         1     ICFZ
2        -1     ICFA
3         1     ICFB
4         1     ICFX
5        -1     ICFY
```